# multiple definition of `main' when including SDL.h

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl-2, clion

after 2 days of research, i finally made it to add the SDL library to my "CLion/Cmake/Windows"-Project.

What i did was:

1. Created a new project in CLion named "sdl_test_vc"
2. I downloaded SDL2-devel-2.0.7-VC.zip from https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php and extracted it in my project folder.
3. I added in my project folder a subdirectory "cmake" with the FindSDL2.cmake from https://github.com/tcbrindle/sdl2-cmake-scripts

This is my Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(sdl_test_vc)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(sdl_test_vc ${SOURCE_FILES})

# SDL2
set(SDL2_PATH "${sdl_test_vc_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2-2.0.7")

# .cmake for finding SDL2: https://github.com/tcbrindle/sdl2-cmake-scripts
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${sdl_test_vc_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
# find_package(SDL2_Image REQUIRED)
# find_package(SDL2_ttf REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
# ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}
# ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(sdl_test_vc ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
# ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
```

After that i created following main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
// Start SDL2
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

// Create a Window in the middle of the screen
SDL_Window *window = 0;

window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!",
                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                          640, 480,
                          SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

// Delay so that we can see the window appear
SDL_Delay(2000);

// Cleanup and Quit
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();

return 0;
}
```

When building the project, i get following error.

```
../SDL2-2.0.7/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[main]+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\sdl_test_vc.dir\build.make:99: sdl_test_vc.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/sdl_test_vc.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/sdl_test_vc.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: sdl_test_vc] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 7):

You are using SDLmain library, that defines a platform-dependent entry point, parses command-line arguments (converting them to utf-8), and then invokes SDL application entry point. So in your code instead of `main()` you should define function

```
int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Note that if `SDL_MAIN_NEEDED` or `SDL_MAIN_AVAILABLE` is defined then SDL will redefine `main` as `SDL_main` automatically so there is no need to change `main` name in your code.