# multiple definition of `main' working with SDL_main

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl

Basically im trying to create a game with SDL2 and Opengl, but I cant get passed this error. I've tried changing SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[]) to regular main but nothing changes. I know this error is due to the SDL_main library but I don't know how to fix it. I've been searching info for some hours now but can't figure it out, the only thing related to this problem I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841026/multiple-definition-of-main-when-including-sdl-h) post, which didn't fix my problem.

**Common.h**

```
#ifndef _COMMON_H
#define _COMMON_H

/*=======STANDARD TEMPLATE LIBRARY=======*/
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/*=======GLU/GLEW=======*/
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
/*=======SDL2=======*/

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>


/*=======CLASS DEFINITIONS=======*/


#endif
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "common.h"

bool isRunning = true;

int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Error Checking/Initialisation
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_NOPARACHUTE & SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        SDL_Log("Unable to initialize SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        //Specify OpenGL Version (4.2)
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
        SDL_Log("SDL Initialised");
    }

    //Create Window Instance
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Game Engine",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        640,
        480,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
    );

    //Check that the window was succesfully created
    if(window == NULL)
    {
        //Print error, if null
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    else
        SDL_Log("Window Successful Generated");


    //Map OpenGL Context to Window
    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

    //Render

    //Swap Render Buffers
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);

    //Free up resources
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glContext);
    SDL_Quit();


    return 0;
}
```

**Error output**

```
./src/lib/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[main]+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
```

**Makefile**

```
all:
    g++ -I ./src/include -L ./src/lib -o ./Builds/Win_Build/engine main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2  -lmingw32 -lopengl32 -lglew32  -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf --verbose
```

**Lib folder**

[image]

EDIT:
I fixed it by redownloading the libraries and using the `.a` extension ones. And also I changed the version of Glew to 64 bits. My new lib folder:

[image]

Comment: What's up with copypasting the flags multiple times? Also, you having `.lib` files is suspicious, since normally those are used with MSVC, not GCC. SDL2 ships `.a` files for GCC.

Comment: I copied an old "SDL library" folder i had in my computer, maybe should've checked it more thoroughly. Should I  delete the ```.lib``` files?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I would delete everything and re-download the libraries, just in case.

Comment: Yeah I changed it, now it says ```C:/Program Files/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible ./src/lib/libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main``` for every one of the libraries. It cannot find them.

Comment: IIRC that's when you try linking 32-bit and 64-bit object files together.

Comment: Where did you get those .a files? The files you've downloaded should have two versions of it, x32 and x64, try both.

Comment: It works, i had to use 64bits version of SDL2 and Glew. I just needed to redownload them all and put only the ones i needed.