# When linking SDL, getting `unresolved external symbol SDL_main`

Tags: c++, sdl

I followed SDL2 installation guide but still i could't make to work

Its shows LNK2019 and LNK1120 error

I downloaded SDL2-devel-2.30.0-VC.zip from the download site
and extracted it in a separate folder.

then i created a new project in visual studio community.

then Debug>Properties and added library, include and linker too.
and also verified i am using the right architect (x64)

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>work.cpp
1>SDL2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_main referenced in function main_getcmdline
1>D:\RayTracing\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 13:19 and took 02.133 seconds ==========
```

i have added the library path to the environmental variable too.

but still i am getting the error

guide me to fix this error

Comment: My crystal ball says wrong `main` signature. SDL requires `int main(int, char **)` (or something similar; `int main()` isn't allowed).

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/FAQWindows#i_get_undefined_reference_to_sdl_main_...

Comment: @RetiredNinja The wiki page clarified my doubt. Thanks.

Comment: But i still don't understand how, int main() works for the tutorial on youtube?

Comment: It's sometimes possible to get away with that. E.g. I don't think Linux has this restriction. On Windows, if you don't link `SDL2main` and undefine `main` it's also not enforced. But what you're doing now is the recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/FAQWindows#i_get_undefined_reference_to_sdl_main_:

> **I get "Undefined reference to 'SDL_main'" ...**
>
> Make sure that you are declaring main() as:
>
> ```
> #include "SDL.h"
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> ```
>
> You should be using main() instead of WinMain() even though you are
> creating a Windows application, because SDL provides a version of
> !WinMain() which performs some SDL initialization before calling your
> main code. If for some reason you need to use !WinMain(), take a look
> at the SDL source code in src/main/win32/SDL_main.c to see what kind
> of initialization you need to do in your !WinMain() function so that
> SDL works properly.

Now i could understand why it didn't work

Comment: SDLmain library overrides entry point, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841026/multiple-definition-of-main-when-including-sdl-h/48841091#48841091

Comment: It doesn't work because it is searching for a specific signature based on the mangled name. There are other ways, both correct and incorrect, to modify that behavior. Since I have not watched countless videos on the subject I can't comment on whatever they have done.

Comment: If you're pasting text from elsewhere, please format it as quote and link to the source.